# Two subspaces isomorphism on direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

Give an example of a vector space W and its two subspaces $U$ and $V$ such that $U + V$ is isomorphic to $U ⊕ V$ and $U ∩ V \ne \{0\}$.

1. shouldn't  $U ∩ V = \{0\}$ since it is a direct sum?
2. So I am having trouble understanding the solution on the example of a polynomial space below:

Let  be span of $\{x^i: i=2n, n \in ℕ\}$ and $$ be span of $\{x^j: j=2n+1 \text{or } j=0\}$. Then note that $+$ recovers the entire vector space of polynomial space. On the other hand $⊕$ is like a polynomial space with an extra copy of constants. Now, note that this vector space has countable basis and is thus isomorphic to $+$ as the polynomial vector space also has countable basis.

How does it recover the entire vector space and how is the direct sum also the entire space? I am having trouble understanding what $U$ and $V$ are.

Comment: You are correct that $U\cap V = \{0\}$ must hold if both $U$ and $V$ are of finite dimension. On the other hand, if either of the subspaces are infinite the result will hold regardless.

Answer (score 1):

If two vector spaces have basis of the same cardinality then they are isomorfic because the bijection between their basis extends to an isomorfism between the vector space.

With this in mind it is easy to see that by taking $W=V$ to be a vector space of infinite dimension and $U$ a non-zero subspace of finite dimension we have an example of what is required.

In fact we can let $U$ be any non-zero vector space but then you need to compare some cardinalities.